# Can anyone explain this error? AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, csv, unicode, encoding, utf-8

From the research I've been doing, this code should write text into a CSV file.

```
import csv
name = "X"
score = "Y"
with open('some.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    data = [["Name", "Score"],
            [name,score]]
    f.write(data[0].encode('utf-8'))        
    writer.writerows(data)
```

At first, it threw me an encoding error. After hunting around on Stack Overflow, I found something about needing to encode the text into UTF8. So I tried encoding with X.encode(). Then I got this:

```
f.write(data[0].encode('utf-8'))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

I can't find an answer as to why this is happening. Can anyone explain why I'm getting this error?

Comment: `data[0]` is `["Name", "Score"]` not a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the csv writer you created.  Don't write `f` directly.  Drop the `f.write` line:

```
import csv
name = "X"
score = "Y"
with open('some.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    data = [["Name", "Score"],
            [name,score]]
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Content of `some.csv`:

```
Name,Score
X,Y
```

Note this is assuming Python 2.  If you are actually on Python 3, and are writing non-ASCII characters, the `open` has different parameters.

```
#coding:utf8
import csv
name = "马克"
score = "Y"
with open('some.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    data = [["Name", "Score"],
            [name,score]]
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got another question: Let's say the name and score variables were user input ie. input(). How would I write the name and score variable then move down a cell and repeat? I thought it was the newline but that seems to do something else.

Comment: `writerows` takes a list of lists as above.  `writerow` takes a single list of the elements in the row.  So you'd just say `writer.writerow([name,score])` for each row you want to add.  the `csv.writer` takes care of adding the delimiters and the newlines.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are getting that error is because you are trying to encode a list, not a string.

I made a working code that wrote "Name" in a .csv file with this script.

```
import csv
name = "X"
score = "Y"
with open('some.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    data = [["Name", "Score"],
            [name,score]]
    f.write(data[0][0].encode('utf-8'))  #<-- Change made here
    #Removed line here
```

On the line that I changed, I added an extra `[0]`.  You data list is nested, which means that there is more than one list inside of it.

If you want to get the `"Name"` string, you need to reference `data[0][0]`. This gets the first element in the outer list, with is `["Name", "Score"]`. The next `[0]` gets the first element is that list, which is `"Name"`.

I got rid of the line with `writer.writerows(data)`. It was throwing me an error and I had no idea what it was supposed to do.